# Need an example of /installfromweb command line switch for Installscript Project Setup.exe

Tags: installscript, installshield-2011

Can anyone please provide me an example of /installfromweb switch in Installshield that is passed to setup.exe ?

I am trying to use this switch with "Installscript project" not "Installscript MSI" for web based Installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer using hit and trial method. Basically the command should be:
setup.exe /installfromweb: